# How to use a forloop to determine number characters that have been input?

Tags: c++, calculator, cin

So i'm still working on my calculator that can do algebraic equations, but I've ran into a bit of a snag. I'm wanting to set the program up to where if you input more than 4 different numbers, it will print a notice on the screen & give you a second chance to do it. However, my forloop isn't working. if 5 characters are input, it asks what type you want to do(the type meaning do you want 4 positive 4 negativee numbers, etc), and then the program resets. Here's what the code looks like(if more information is required I will update the thread as requested):

```
else if (type == "foil")
{
    cout << "Please input the value of X1, X2, Y1, and Y2 (Example: 8 9 4 9)\n";
    cin >> X1 >> X2 >> Y1 >> Y2;
    int nCount = 0;
    for (nCount == cin.beg; nCount != cin.end; nCount++)
    {
        if (nCount > 4)
        {
            printf("Please input 4 diffent numbers.\n");
            Sleep(1000);
            return main();
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
//after forloop is when you're given a chance to input the different         
//combinations foil can have, 2 negative 2 positive, 4 negative, 4 positive, etc.
}
```

Comment: I think there is *less* information required. You should remove everything that is not related to the problem, such as that `while(1)` loop, all the `std::cout` output, the `Sleep` call, `toupper`, `_getche` and so on...

Comment: Ahh alright, sorry just wanted to make sure that I didn't miss anything. I'll go ahead & edit out that stuff.

Comment: The point is that the question should not contain any redundant extra stuff, nor should it be too short to actually exhibit the problem. See http://sscce.org/.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Cleaned it up to show only where the initial problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i guess there are several things to you problem.
First of all you loop will always break in the first iteration, becouse your if statement will take the else branch ALWAYS.
The statement `nCount > 4` will always be false while entering the for loop.

The second problem is `nCount == cin.beg; nCount != cin.end; nCount++`
i would guess the extraction operator removes the bytes from the stream, can't find any refrence atm. So you can't determine the size with it for sure.

I would recommend to do something like this to verify user input.

```
char accepted = 'n';
do {
    accepted = 'n'
    cout << "Please input the value of X1, X2, Y1, and Y2 (Example: 8 9 4 9)\n";
    cin >> X1 >> X2 >> Y1 >> Y2;
    cin.clear();

    //Print out values
    cout << "Are those values corrent? y/n"
    cin >> accepted;
    cin.clear();
} while (accepted != 'y');
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a `std::vector` to hold your variables:

```
std::vector<int> values(4);
cout << "Please input the value of X1, X2, Y1, and Y2 (Example: 8 9 4 9)\n";
for (unsigned int i = 0;
    (cin.good()) && (i < 4);
    ++i)
{
    cin >> values[i];
}
if (values.size() < 4)
{
  // handle error
}
```

By your variable naming convention, your program would be better if you package your values as `Points`, `Coordinates` or `pair`s.

```
struct Coordinate
{
  int x;
  int y;
  friend istream& operator>>(istream& inp, Coordinate& p);
};

istream& operator>>(istream& inp, Coordinate& p)
{
  inp >> p.x >> p.y;
  return inp;
}

int main(void)
{
  Coordinate p1;
  Coordinate p2;
  cout << "Please input point 1:";
  if (!(cin >> p1))
  {
    cerr << "Error inputting point 1.\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  cout << "\nPlease input point 2:";
  if (!(cin >> p2))
  {
    cerr << "Error inputting point 2.\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  // ...
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but by doing so that'll require the whole program to be rewritten correct? Especially the part of the program for foil, since it outputs this(and different variations of it):

   cout << "Answer:" << "-" << (X1 * Y1) << "x " << "-" << (X1 * Y2) << "y " << "-" << (X2 * Y1) << "x " << "-" << (X2 * Y2) << "y " << "\n";